# JavaFX CSS ignores text fill

Tags: css, javafx

I'm having trouble coloring a custom object text in JavaFX.
If I use in line CSS such as:

```
final String chronoStyle = "-fx-font: 50pt \"Arial\"; -fx-text-fill: #3be000;";
```

combined with:

`chronoTotal.setChronoStyle(chronoStyle);
chronoPartial.setChronoStyle(chronoStyle);`

it works perfectly; but because I'm trying to incapsulate every CSS styling element in a .css file, I tried:

```
.chronoStyle {
     -fx-font.size: 50pt;
     -fx-text-fill: #f20e0e;
}

.chronoLap {
     -fx-font-size: 50pt;
     -fx-text-fill: #3dc90a;
}
```

in addition with:

```
chronoTotal.getStyleClass().add("chronoStyle");
chronoPartial.getStyleClass().add("chronoStyle");
```

it doesn't override and I'm stuck with a standard color which I don't know where comes from. Any ideas?

The setChronoStyle(style) method is a custom one due to object structure.

```
public void setChronoStyle(final String style) {
    labelMillis.setStyle(style);
    labelMinutes.setStyle(style);
    labelSeconds.setStyle(style);
    semicolon1.setStyle(style);
    semicolon2.setStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Are other changes in the css file applied? What if you create a rule for `.root`? If it doesn't work it means there is a problem with the loading or assigning of the stylesheet file itself, so you may need to provide the code you used to set it to your scene/stage/root-node...

Comment: Here the whole CSS code: https://pastebin.com/Q5n0LG0U

Comment: Do the rest of the rules in the CSS get applied? Or are they all ignored?

Comment: they all get applied correctly.

Comment: You have a typo : `-fx-font.size:` should be `-fx-font-size:`. Maybe the parser skips the selector because of that.

Comment: Ah the difference is that in `setChronoStyle` you set the styles of the sub-controls directly , so `chronoTotal` is a container (`VBox` or similar). It contains labels, and I don't know which controls I guess. So you could update the selector as `.chronoStyle * { ... }` to apply the attributes to everything inside the container. Or `.chronoStyle .label {...}` to apply only for `Label`s.

Comment: Yes `chronoTotal` is an object of a custom class extending an HBox. I'm sorry but I didn't quite get what should I do to make it work.